# Trying to sum 2 tables where some entries do not exist in the other

Tags: sql, left-join, inner-join, right-to-left

I would like to do a join with a sum that will use both tables.  I want to show 0 for the Tax Codes that are not in Table 2.  Is there a join I can use that will have the results of 150 for INS1 and 0 for INS2?

Table 1

| TaxCode | FilingCode |
| --- | --- |
| INS1 | INS |
| INS2 | INS |

Table 2

| TaxCode | Payment |
| --- | --- |
| INS1 | 50.00 |
| INS1 | 100.00 |

Answer (score 1):

You just need a simple left-outer join,

```
Select t1.TaxCode, sum(coalesce(Payment,0)) Payment
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on t2.Taxcode=t1.Taxcode
group by t1.Taxcode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1.TaxCode,t1.FillingCode, sum(nvl(Payment,0)) as Payment
from Table1 t1
left outer join Table2 t2 on t1.Taxcode=t2.Taxcode
group by t1.Taxcode,t1.FillingCode;
```

Comment: It wound up being more complicated than that.  I had to do left join with unions and cross joins

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a solution to something like this, my query that worked is below

```
 SELECT 
     T.TRAN_CODE,
     SUM(ISNULL(TF.PAYMENT, 0)) AS PrePayment
   FROM 
    Tranctl AS T
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
            T.TRAN_CODE,
            0 AS PAYMENT
        FROM 
          Tranctl AS T
        CROSS JOIN Tran_File AS TF
        UNION ALL SELECT 
            TF.TRAN_CODE,
            TF.PAYMENT AS PrePayment
        FROM Tran_File AS TF 
        WHERE 
            TF.ID = '10175'
        AND TF.TAX_YEAR = '2021'
    ) TF ON T.TRAN_CODE = TF.TRAN_CODE 
WHERE 
    T.Filing_Code = 'INS'
GROUP BY 
    T.TRAN_CODE
```